# Do I need to include support-v7/appcompat?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

My Android game doesn't reference any resources defined in [`extras-android-support-v7/appcompat`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#v7-appcompat).
(The app doesn't use `ActionBar` or `material design` user interface).
The project compiles without errors when `appcompat` is not included as library.

Do I still need to include `appcompat`, in case it is referenced from `AdMob`, `GoogleAnalytics` or `GoogleGames` `play-services` libraries?

Answer (score 1):

> in case it is referenced from AdMob, GoogleAnalytics or GoogleGames play-services libraries?

Those libraries shouldn't bind you to Material Design or extra asset resources requiring `appcompat-v7`.

If you wanted to use Support Fragments, though, it would be a good idea to include at least `support-v4`